# Login page "mysqli_query"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am setting up a web server with sql database
been watching a video on it everything looked like it was working up until this issues

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT (`id`) FROM users WHERE username = '$con,$username'");
    return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}
?>
```

Recoverable fatal error:

> Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\core\functions\users.php on line 5

***Note***:- I have taken reference from this Video, but i have changed `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til3oVNlho4]

Comment: `mysqli_result()` is not a function.

Comment: this video is *anything* but good.

Comment: dont pass $con in where clause, try mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT (`id`) FROM users WHERE username = '$username');

Answer (score 4):

A few things to note,

1. The connection object needs to be visible in the scope of the function. The best way of doing that, is by passing the argument into the function (avoid using `global` or creating a connection within the function).
2. `mysqli_result()` is not a function that exists in `mysqli_`. It existed only in `mysql_`, which is deprecated and should not be used.
3. When dealing with user-input or any sort of variable, its better to use a prepared statement
4. You can return the expression `$count == 0` instead of `$count == 0 ? true : false`, as they are equivalent.

```php
function user_exists($username, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) 
                            FROM users 
                            WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    return $count == 0;

}
```

Now, when you're calling it, remember to pass in the `$conn` argument (or whatever your connection object is defined as).

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'databasename'); // Change credentials accordingly
if (user_exists($username, $conn)) {
    // User does exist!
} else {
    // User does not exist
}
```

Comment: this one seems to be the perfect answer among all.+1

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the database name in the [mysqli_connect](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) function and the connection variable is needed to be passed as the first parameter. You can remove `COUNT` from the query and use [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.w3schools.com/php7/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp) to count the number of rows.

```
 $username = sanitize($username);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','databasename');//<- database name is required
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT (`id`) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
return (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ) ? true : false;
```

I suggest you to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent from sql injections

Answer (score 0):

**use mysqli_fetch_row() function. it will fetch one row**

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT (`id`) FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);  
    return ($result[0] == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```